# Search empty string in searchbar : Objective-c

Tags: ios, xcode, search, uisearchbar, string

I want to allow user to **search an empty string** in searchbar. Whenever user enters any text the search button of keyboard becomes active. However if searchbar is empty then search button of keyboard is inactive. I have tried on below delegates but didn't worked.

```
- (void) searchBar:(UISearchBar *)theSearchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText {

  ... 
}

- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
  ...
}
```

[image: Scrrenshot]

Any fix for this problem? Sure +1 for correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

However this looks bad, its exactly what you want.

You need to customize `UITextField` inside `UISearchBar`

```
    @try {
        for (id object in [[[search subviews] firstObject] subviews])
        {
            if (object && [object isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]])
            {
                UITextField *textFieldObject = (UITextField *)object;
                //textFieldObject.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeySearch;
                textFieldObject.enablesReturnKeyAutomatically = NO;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSLog(@"Error while customizing UISearchBar");
    }
    @finally {

    }
```

Here, search is `UISearchBar`.

Hope this will work for you ! :)

FYI, this is working great in iOS7 and 8.1.1 too. Not checked with < 7.0 and > 8.1.1

Comment: Yes definitely, because here we're not using any private APIs here. Just digging into `UISearchBar`.

Answer (score 2):

A simple way set to search text like below

```
-(void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar{
    //Add a blank character to hack search button enable
    searchBar.text = @" ";
}
```